# Using Charles Proxy how do you change your IP address (Making it look like it's from another country)

Tags: charles-proxy, iproute

I have a requirement where I have to route traffic from different countries to mobile application.

I want traffic coming from different countries IP addresses to  mobile application. (USA, Australia etc...)

I would really appreciate it if anyone can share knowledge regarding how i can simulate this using Charles proxy.

Answer (score 2):

From: https://community.openx.com/s/article/How-Do-I-Test-a-Campaign-that-Is-GeoTargeted-Using-Charles-Proxy-Tool-or-Modify-Headers-FireFox-Plugin

1. Tools >> Rewrite
2. Check off "Enable Rewrite"
3. Click on "Add"
4. Name the rule such as "Geo CA"
5. Click on "Add" under Locations and leave all the fields empty and hit OK. You will see an "*" under Locations. This means that *all* HTTP calls will contain this X-FORWARDED-FOR header
6. Under "Rules", hit "Add" and fill in

Type: Add Header
"Request" Checked off
Leave Match Name/Value fields empty
New: "Name" X-FORWARDED-FOR

"Value" Ip address of California. You can utilize 12.175.177.115
to mimic a Los Angeles address.

Please use a different IP address to mimic other locations.